# azure service bus keeps messages after I receive them

Tags: azure, servicebus

I've written some code to delete test messages off a service bus topic.  I'm the only one using this topic.  It's using ReceiveAndDelete mode so I am assuming it's going to delete them, but every time I run the code it goes through this cycle of receiving messages, so I know it's not deleting them.  What am I doing wrong?

```
   public void TruncateTopic()
    {
        // reset topic for testing..
        SubscriptionClient client = SubscriptionClient.CreateFromConnectionString(
            connStr, QUEUENAME, "AllMessages",ReceiveMode.ReceiveAndDelete);
        BrokeredMessage message = client.Peek();
        while (message != null)
        {
            client.Receive();
            message = client.Peek();
        }
        client.Close();

    }
```

Comment: If I use the default receive mode (peeklock) I can
   Complete()
the message, and it seems to delete.  But surely ReceiveAndDelete mode should delete after receiving, as in the microsoft documentation?

Answer (score 1):

In your code you only do `Peek` on the Topic/Queue. Peek action never deletes the messages.

As you can clearly [read from documentation Peek method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj908822.aspx) only `peeks` into the subscription without actually `receiving` the message.

The `ReceiveAndDelete` receive mode will well work when you not just [Peek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj908822.aspx) the messages but [Receive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.subscriptionclient.receive.aspx) them instead! That is why it is named `ReceiveAndDelete` but not `PeekAndDelete`.

Change your code to:

```
    BrokeredMessage message = client.Receive();
    while (message != null)
    {
        message = client.Receive();
    }
```

And everything will be fine.

Comment: it does receive.  that's the line
   client.Receive();